# Remove separation between bar and axis line in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to remove the distance between the bar and the axis line in a JFreeChart bar chart?

I have produced a bar chart that looks like (A), but I would like it to look like (B), i.e. without any separation between the bar and the (darker) axis line. The axis line is configured as:

```
    plot.getDomainAxis().setAxisLinePaint(new Color(0x333333));
    plot.getDomainAxis().setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
```

I couldn't find the relevant setting for this purpose.

[image: (A) actual and (B) intended chart]

Edit: the demo chart at [BarRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html) javadoc, also shows the same issue.

[image]

Comment: @trashgod BarChartDemo1 is a MCVE. Despite of the bars starting at zero, there is some space between them and the **axis line**. My question is if that space is configurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That space is called [axis offset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html#setAxisOffset-org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets-). The `StandardChartTheme` applies an `axisOffset` of 4px.

In order to remove the axis offset configure:

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

The axis offset can also be configured at the theme level: [StandardChartTheme.setAxisOffset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/StandardChartTheme.html#setAxisOffset-org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets-)

Answer (score 0):

remove the margin with:

```
BarRenderer(renderer)).setItemMargin(0.0);
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't produce any effect. Also, from the documentation: «The value is expressed as a percentage of the available width for plotting all the bars, with the resulting amount to be distributed between all the bars»

Comment: damm yes you are right, it remove the space between the bars...   sorry

Comment: but i think it is a margin thing from the axis line

Comment: Yes, I undesrtand that setItemMargin manages the separation *between bars* (actually I didn't see any difference in that sense either, but I have few bars and reduced space). I couldn't find a setter for the distance from the axis line